# How to count Up and Down using For Loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, arduino, nested-loops

I want to get output like this using nested for loops:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 3
1 2
1 1
1 0
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 3
3 2
3 1
3 0
```

So I came up with this solution:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++) {    
 if(i == 1){      
  for(j=3;j>=0;--j) {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(j);       
  }      
}else if(i == 3){      
  for(j=3;j>=0;--j) {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(j);     
  }      
}else{
  for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(j);
  }      
}
}
```

This works but is there way to do this without if conditions inside the loops?

Comment: What is `Serial.print()`?  Is this C or C++?

Comment: @jwdonahue its arduino serial.print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not the Arduino guy, but as its similar to C and this question is more about the algorithm let me sketch an approach in C:

```
#define LEFT_START (0)
#define LEFT_END (3)
#define RIGHT_START (0)
#define RIGHT_END (3)

enum DIRECTION {
  DOWN = -1,
  UP = 1
};

int main(void)
{
  for (int direction = UP, i = LEFT_START, j = RIGHT_START - sign; 
    i <= LEFT_END; 
    ++i, direction *= -1)
  {
    for (j += direction;
      j >= RIGHT_START && j <= RIGHT_END;
      j += direction)
    {
      printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
    }
  }
}
```

No if/then, not explicitly, nor implicitly via ternary-operator, BTW. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 3;

    for ( int i = 0; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j <= N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d %d\n", i , i % 2 == 0 ? j : N - j );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 3
1 2
1 1
1 0
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 3
3 2
3 1
3 0
```

Or the loops can be written like

```
const int N = 4;

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    {
        printf( "%d %d\n", i , i % 2 == 0 ? j : N - j - 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Didn't the OP ask for a solution "*without if conditions inside the loops*"? ;)

Comment: @alk There is no if statements. He means his numerous if statements.

Comment: "*There is no if statements*" C'mon, a ternary-operator is semantically the same as an if-then.

Comment: @alk It seems you have nothing to do. It is totally clear that he does not like if-else statements with for loops inside them. That is all.

Comment: "*seems you have nothing to do*" you are absolutely right. "Having nothing to do" is a major prerequisite do spent my time here. You are at work? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your purpose was, but you need to use if statement. This code will do the thing you want

```
int n =3;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   for (int i=0; i<=n; i++){
       if(i%2 == 0){
           for (int j=0; j<=n; j++){
               Serial.print(i);
               Serial.print(" ");
               Serial.println(j); 
           }
       }
       else{
           for (int j=n; j>=0; j--){
               Serial.print(i);
               Serial.print(" ");
               Serial.println(j); 
           }
      }
   }
}
```

The output looks like this,
[image]
Defining variables/constant `n`, `i`, `j` is entirely up to you based on your project. This code is just a simple demonstration.

Comment: Thats also not the output wanted. please check the posted output.  it should looks like this 0-0,0-1,0-2,0-3,    1-3, 1-2, 1-1, 1-0

Comment: You need to use one `if{}else{}` statement

Comment: Btw updated my answer, Sorry for not reading the question properly:) cheers mate!